# Is there any evidence that the Dunning-Kruger Effect applies to self-appraisals of soundness or reasonableness of judgement?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, intelligence, metacognition

The Dunning-Kruger Effect is the peculiar phenomenon wherein those with the lowest ability also have impaired metacognition, resulting in a peculiar overestimation of their ability e.g. stupid person who thinks they're a genius. This is known as miscalibration.

The figure below characterises the matter perfectly:

[image]

> Kruger, J., & Dunning, D. (1999). Unskilled and unaware of it: How difficulties in recognizing one’s own incompetence lead to inflated self-assessments. *Journal of Personality and Social Psychology*, 77, 1121–1134. https://doi.org/10.1037/0022-3514.77.6.1121

Now, to my understanding the Dunning-Kruger Effect tracks onto a wide variety of domains, not just intelligence. For example, the above paper looked at humour, grammar and reasoning ability.

**Question: Is there any literature relating to the Dunning-Kruger Effect and reasonableness or *soundness of judgement?***

In other words, I want to know if the most unreasonable people will also believe that they are actually very reasonable? I note that this has nothing to do with reasoning ability, but I am sure that there is an element to it as well. It does not need to be the Dunning-Kruger Effect, but something similar.

Comment: I removed the bit about the personal situation because it didn't contribute to the question. I think it's now a decent question, but I think *reasonableness* is probably not the correct term here, even though it is effectively a synonym of sound judgment, it implies a good deal of subjective assessment.